# White spaces added at end of body

Tags: css

I am having the following css

```
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position:relative;
}

body {
background-color: #fff;
border-top: solid 10px #000;
color: #333;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#content{
background-color: #efeeef;
clear: both;
padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

And its my HTML Page

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">             
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
 </div>
```

[image]

If the content of body is small white spaces are added like in the above image(white spaces added in the red mark).
How can I remove that? Any help?

Comment: Why do you even have `<div id="body">`?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want to remove the added white spaces below the body

Comment: Inside that div I am having contentplaceholder. Thats why set id like that. I think this will not be the problem. Because <body> tag is different than an element with id body

Comment: @BoltClock what's wrong with `id="body"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `min-height` for content :-

```
#content{
background-color: #fffaaa;
clear: both;
padding-bottom: 35px;
min-height:600px;
}​
```

see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8KgWY/)

Comment: Thanks. Its great. This was I need. But if I set min-height as default size means, height will differ for different size of monitors know? So scroll bar will be visible event if content is less for small height monitor of mine. Is it possible to avoid that scroll bar if content is less?

Comment: yes ..so try to play with "scroll:overflow" for a given height.